# How works following-sibling with elements like strong?

Tags: xpath

On [the URL](https://www.bobswatches.com/pre-owned-rolex-submariner-116610lv-ceramic-hulk.html) I’m trying to get with XPath the content of certain HTML element, like on the screenshot:
[image]

I tried it with multiple XPaths and settings, like

`//td[contains(@class, "productTitle")]/strong[contains(text(),"Movement:")]/following-sibling::td`

`//td[@class="productTitle"]/strong[text()="Movement:"]/following-sibling::td`

But nothing worked for me.

Only the variant `//td[contains(@class, "productTitle")]/following-sibling::td` worked partly for me (getting all elements, and not the single one I'm looking for), and it doesn’t match my need, because I **need** the relation on the content of the `<strong>`-element, to get the column heading.

Comment: you need to post a valid, complete XML example as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no following-sibling `td` when the context is `strong`, so you'd have to go back up to the parent.

Example (untested)...

```xml
//td[contains(@class, "productTitle")]/strong[contains(text(),"Movement:")]/../following-sibling::td
```

However, I would prefer selecting the correct `tr` based on the first `td` and then selecting the second `tr` (also untested)...

```xml
//tr[td[1][contains(@class,'productTitle')][contains(.,'Movement:')]]/td[2]
```